# Grails --illegal attempt to dereference collection error in Hql

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, hql, grails-orm

I have a Training domain class

```
    class Training {

     String type
     Date createdOn
     Date modifiedOn

    static belongsTo = [course: Course]
    static hasMany = [attachments: Attachment]
  }
```

and i have Course domain class

```
     class Course {

          String name

          static hasMany = [trainings: Training, tracks: Track]
          static belongsTo = Track
   }
```

and Track domain class

```
    class Track {
        String name 
    }
```

i want to select the training based on track.

now say i get track id's and i want to retrieve the  training based on Track id

i tried query something like this

```
 def query = "FROM Training AS t WHERE  t.course.tracks.id IN (1,2)"
  trainingList = Training.findAll(query)
```

it gives

```
 illegal attempt to dereference collection
```

error.. because i cannot do `t.course.tracks.id`

help me to write correct hql query to get the training if i have track id's (say 1, 2)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is this

```
def query = "FROM Training AS t join t.course as c join c.tracks as tr WHERE  tr.id IN (1,2)"
trainingList = Training.findAll(query)
```

The problem is when you attempt to go from one to many.

Answer (score -1):

Please find below the HQL to retrieve all the trainings for tracid 1 & 2.

> from Course c, Track tr, Training t where tr.courceid= c.courceid  and
>   tr.trackid=c.tracid and tr.trackid in (1,2)